# Taking all definition for a word from xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have the following XML

```
<entry_list version="1.0">
<entry id="sweet tooth">
  <ew>sweet tooth</ew>
  <hw>sweet tooth</hw>
  <fl>noun</fl>
  <def>
    <date>14th century</date>
    <dt>:a craving or fondness for sweet food</dt>
  </def>
</entry>
</entry_list>
```

How do i only show the "a craving or fondness for sweet food" part? The XML is placed in a textbox but i want the textbox to just show the craving line.

Also, if i search for something less specific such as "Computer" there are many definitions. How do i pick the earliest definition? Here is the XML for Computer

```
   <entry_list version="1.0">
  <entry id="computer">
    <ew>computer</ew>
    <subj>CP#IS</subj>
    <hw>com*put*er</hw>
    <sound>
      <wav>comput06.wav</wav>
      <wpr>kum-!pyU-tur</wpr>
    </sound>
    <pr>kﾉ冦-ﾋ・yﾃｼ-tﾉ决</pr>
    <fl>noun</fl>
    <lb>often attributive</lb>
    <def>
      <date>1646</date>
      <dt>:one that <fw>computes</fw></dt>
      <sd>specifically</sd>
      <dt>:a programmable usually electronic device that can store, retrieve, and process data</dt>
    </def>
    <uro>
      <ure>com*put*er*dom</ure>
      <sound>
        <wav>comput07.wav</wav>
        <wpr>kum-!pyU-tur-dum</wpr>
      </sound>
      <pr>-dﾉ冦</pr>
      <fl>noun</fl>
    </uro>
    <uro>
      <ure>com*put*er*less</ure>
      <sound>
        <wav>comput08.wav</wav>
        <wpr>kum-!pyU-tur-lus</wpr>
      </sound>
      <pr>-lﾉ冱</pr>
      <fl>adjective</fl>
    </uro>
    <uro>
      <ure>com*put*er*like</ure>
      <sound>
        <wav>comput09.wav</wav>
        <wpr>kum-!pyU-tur-+lIk</wpr>
      </sound>
      <pr>-ﾋ畦ﾄｫk</pr>
      <fl>adjective</fl>
    </uro>
  </entry>
  <entry id="computer science">
    <ew>computer science</ew>
    <subj>CP</subj>
    <hw>computer science</hw>
    <fl>noun</fl>
    <def>
      <date>1961</date>
      <dt>:a branch of science that deals with the theory of computation or the design of computers</dt>
    </def>
  </entry>
  <entry id="analog computer">
    <ew>analog computer</ew>
    <subj>CP</subj>
    <hw>analog computer</hw>
    <fl>noun</fl>
    <def>
      <date>1948</date>
      <dt>:a computer that operates with numbers represented by directly measurable quantities (as voltages or rotations) <dx>compare <dxt>digital computer</dxt><dxt>hybrid computer</dxt></dx></dt>
    </def>
  </entry>
  <entry id="digital computer">
    <ew>digital computer</ew>
    <subj>CP</subj>
    <hw>digital computer</hw>
    <fl>noun</fl>
    <def>
      <date>1947</date>
      <dt>:a computer that operates with numbers expressed directly as digits <dx>compare <dxt>analog computer</dxt><dxt>hybrid computer</dxt></dx></dt>
    </def>
  </entry>
  <entry id="home computer">
    <ew>home computer</ew>
    <subj>CP</subj>
    <hw>home computer</hw>
    <fl>noun</fl>
    <def>
      <date>1976</date>
      <dt>:a personal computer used in the home</dt>
    </def>
  </entry>
  <entry id="hybrid computer">
    <ew>hybrid computer</ew>
    <subj>CP</subj>
    <hw>hybrid computer</hw>
    <fl>noun</fl>
    <def>
      <date>1968</date>
      <dt>:a computer system consisting of a combination of analog and digital computer systems</dt>
    </def>
  </entry>
  <entry id="personal computer">
    <ew>personal computer</ew>
    <subj>CP</subj>
    <hw>personal computer</hw>
    <fl>noun</fl>
    <def>
      <date>1976</date>
      <dt>:a general-purpose computer equipped with a microprocessor and designed to run especially commercial software (as a word processor or Internet browser) for an individual user</dt>
    </def>
  </entry>
</entry_list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Step by step

1. How about first write a c# application to read xml?
2. Select needed xml tag
3. Display it out.

Read xml in C# can be found at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-and-writing-xml-in-C-Sharp/ (stream way)
For small xml, prefer DOM (read all in at once), that way, it's a little bitter easy: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/

Select xml tag, can be a switch statement in your for loop in the first case; or just as easy as select node and attribute in DOM case.

Display in WPF, should be easiest of all. Just pass this value to WPF.

Hope helps,

I should write comment above, but with company merging, domain change, I lost my email address. I have no enough point to write comment in SO. So put answer here. Hope helps you and also helps me build points.

Answer (score 0):

try xml linq like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string word = "computer";

            List<XElement> computers = doc.Descendants("entry").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == word).ToList();

            var definitions = computers.Select(x => new {
                word = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                definitions = x.Elements("def").Select(y => new {
                    dts = y.Elements("dt").Select(z => (string)z).ToList()
                }).FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```